# Trouble setting timeout in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, settimeout

I have a domain exception handler (wrapper for nightwatch tests).

**my exception handler wrapper**

```
var domainError = function(func) {

    return function() {
      var d = domain.create().on('error', function(err) {
        console.error(err.stack);
      });

      d.enter();
      try {
        return func.apply(this, arguments);
      }
      catch (err) {
        //do something with the err
      }
      d.exit();
    }
};
```

I am trying to set timeouts so that `return func.apply(this, arguments);` doesn't take forever.

Could anyone suggest how I can add timeouts and make the domain end the function and exit, if it exceeds timeout?

Comment: does that func work synchronously?

Comment: yes. domainerror function works synchronously..@MustafaDokumacı

Answer (score 7):

This is impossible in Node's concurrency model. There are no "interrupts" - multiprocessing is done cooperatively. If you look at it from the other side - you get a really powerful guarantee that your code will almost always run to completion.

You can spawn another child process and then preempt that (since processes support preemption).

---

The *easiest* way to terminate a synchronous function is to execute it in its own "isolate" - meaning it can be killed. Note that this is not as performant as making a dedicated worker "process" and using async io to communicate with it - which is probably faster - but this is easier.

```
var vm = require('vm'); // get the VM module

// when you want to run a bit 
function withError(func, context, timeout){
     var ctx = vm.createContext(context);
     var code = func.toString().slice(12).slice(0,-2)
     return vm.runInContext(code, ctx, {
        timeout: timeout,
        displayErrors: true; // to log, like in your version
     });
}
```

Note that this code means **the function has no access to closure scope or arguments**, so everything needs to be in its scope - it's not as big of an issue as you might think since you can convert:

```
function doFoo(x, y){
    return x + y + z; // z is from closure
}
```

Into

```
function doFoo(){
    return this.x + this.y + this.z;
}
```

And call it as

```
withError(doFoo, {x:x, y:y, z:z }, 2000); // 2000 ms timeout
```

This can also be better automated by using a lexical analysis tool that generates a syntax tree.

If I may suggest an alternative - write your `func` in a way that it can yield control - cooperative multitasking is a lot easier and less error prone in these cases.

Answer (score -3):

or else
use npm -install timer-stopwatch

[timer stopwatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timer-stopwatch)

cool ??

Comment: I don't think you understood the problem. This has nothing to do with any of those, this is about server-side JavaScript, and stopping synchronous code...

Comment: Clearly the *answer* does not address the question.

Comment: Does node.js is server-side and source code is "like" javascript and uses same paradigms as client-side ?

Comment: No, events work differently from the DOM (no preventDefault etc) and no jQuery... Even if they worked the same way - this would still be irrelevant.

Comment: it's a synchronous call...is it what you expected ??
But, i understand that the above code on("error") is similar as a delegate in C#.NET. And for delegates in c#, you are able to write something that :
a.Error += func_error;
thus, a.Error -= func_error is for removing the delegate; to prevent to rerun the function and adding twice the same func_error, you should remove the old delegate call first.
C# delegate are synchronous calls; even, jQuery paradigms are synchronous calls too. What's wrong ?